# $location path removing parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular and have a complex URL with many parameters, something along the lines of `http://localhost:3000/#/faaacceptance?FAAFreqNauticalMileOption=20`

For some reason, when I do the following:

```
var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
var test1= $location.path();
var test2= $location.url();
```

All returned a url without the the query parameters.

It only returns `http://localhost:3000/#/faaacceptance`

All of my parameters after `?` are getting removed and I cannot figure out why. After the controller finishes loading, all of the url parameters in the url bar are removed.
I am using the triangular admin theme, and this started happening after I updated it, but I am not sure if there is some other way I could figure out what is wrong, as I cannot find where in the theme this would be happening. I also updated angular to the newest version, so perhaps something changed. Thank you for any help/

Comment: Actually, it should only return `/faaacceptance`. Why should it return the query parameters? Have you read the documentation of this method? If not, then do.

Comment: From docs: $location.path() => _Return path of current url when called **without** any parameter._

Comment: Using $windows.location was the only thing that seemed to show the full url. I had a break point on $location and none of the options had more than a truncated url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the window.location object that has all the necessary attributes that you need.

Comment: Using $window.location is the ONLY thing that allowed me to get the full url. EVERY url in the $location only had a shorted version and had all query prams striped out. I am not sure why at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior and `$location.path` works exactly as described in the documentation.

> Return path of current url when called without any parameter.
>
> Change path when called with parameter and return $location.
>
> Note: Path should always begin with forward slash (/), this method
>   will add the forward slash if it is missing.

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var path> = $location.path(); 
// => "/some/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the below

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var path = $location.path(); 
// => "/some/path"
```

So if you require the full path use

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
// => "http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

or only the parameter path use

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var url = $location.url();
// => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried the following: var absUrl = $location.absUrl(); var ewer = $location.path(); var ewer = $location.url(); All returned a url without the the query parameters. Using $windows.location was the only thing that seemed to show the full url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the url param you have to use `$routeParams` who is an object with the param/value

```
app.controller('addController', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$location',
        function ($scope, $routeParams,$location) {

            console.log($routeParams);

}]);
```

You can create a function who take  $routeParams object and recreate the query params like you want

Comment: Hmm, the problem is I have a system that is generating complex URLS that are saved in a string and used to reload the state of a system, so I need to be able to get the query params from the url, which was 100% working fine before I upgraded some libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **state.go** for this kind of navigation ...

THis example will simplify your code

http://luxiyalu.com/reference-state-go-with-parameter/